# Calculate the the integral $\int_1^2(\sqrt{1+4v}-2\sqrt{v})dv$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I need to calculate the following integral :

$$\int_1^2(\sqrt{1+4v}-2\sqrt{v})dv$$

This is what I did :

$$\int_1^2(\sqrt{1+4v}-2\sqrt{v})dv=|t=1+4v,dt=4dv,\frac{dt}{4}=dv|=\frac{1}{4}\int_5^9\sqrt{t}dt-2\int_1^2\sqrt{v}dv=\\ \frac{1}{6}\int_5^9t^{1.5}dt-2\int_1^2\sqrt{v}dv=\frac{1}{6}(1+4v)^{1.5}|^9_5-\frac{4}{3}(v^{1.5})|^2_1=\\ \frac{1}{6}((1+36)^{1.5}-(1+20)^{1.5})-(\frac{4}{3}(2^{1.5}-1^{1.5}))=19.03345117$$

Which is wrong (Checked via Wolframalpha)

Any idea what's wrong?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Why you did substitute $t$ again with $v$ while using the changed bounds?!!! It should be $\frac{1}{6}{t^{1.5}}|_5^9$

Comment: @RezaH.Khayyami Shouldn't I go back to terms of $v$ after substitution?

Comment: No, It's integral with new variable and new integral bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\int_1^2(\sqrt{1+4v}-2\sqrt{v})dv&=\int_1^2\sqrt{1+4v}dv-2\int_1^2\sqrt{v}dv\\
&=\frac16(1+4v)^{3/2}\Big|_{v=1}^{v=2}-\frac43 v^{3/2}\Big|_{v=1}^{v=2}\\
&=(\frac92-\frac{5\sqrt5}{6})-(\frac{8\sqrt2}{3}-\frac43)\\
&=\frac16(35-16\sqrt2-5\sqrt5)\\
&=0.198707...
\end{align}